# Benefits/downsides of defining function that is discontinuous at a point "explicitly" vs using piecewise?

Tags: functions, function-construction, piecewise, discontinuity

For example, suppose I wanted to define a function, `f` that is $f(x)=x^2$ except at $x=1$, where $f(x)=5$

Two ways I can define this are

```
f[1]=5;
f[x_]:=x
```

or

```
g[x_]:= Piecewise[{{5,x==1}},x^2]
```

What are the benefits/downsides of one approach vs the other? Or are they the same?

Comment: You didn't mention using `If[]` statement or `Which[]` They are different. The first method uses two patterns. There are several benefits/pitfalls, but that requires much explaining.

Comment: @Somos Sorry for not mentioning.

Comment: Another way: `f[x_]:=Which[x==1,5,True,x^2]`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

They differ in how they handle the function's derivative.

```
Clear["Global`*"]

f1[1] = 5;
f1[x_] := x^2

f1'[x]

(* 2 x *)

f1'[1]

(* 2 *)

f2[x_] := Piecewise[{{5, x == 1}}, x^2]

f2'[x]

(* Piecewise[{{0, x == 1}}, 2*x] *)

f2'[1]

(* 0 *)

f3[x_] := Piecewise[{{x^2, x < 1 || x > 1}}, 5]

f3'[x]

(* Piecewise[{{2*x, x < 1 || x > 1}}, Indeterminate] *)

f3'[1]

(* Indeterminate *)
```

Comment: Oof. Thanks. Wouldn't the second technically be better if we cared about derivatives then?

Comment: I would think that the third is better.

Answer (score 5):

When you write

```
f[1] = 5;
f[x_] := x
```

you are specifying how expressions will be rewritten during evaluation. `f[1]` is just a pattern: any expression that matches that pattern will be rewritten as `5`. The 'Blank' pattern represents anything else, so:

```
f[y]
(* y *)
```

The possibility that `y` might take the value `1` at some later stage of the computation isn't taken into account.

One the other hand:

```
g[x_] := Piecewise[{{5, x == 1}}, x^2]
g[y]
(* Piecewise[{{5, y == 1}}, y^2] *)
```

This treats `y` properly as a variable.

Note that symbolic mathematics in *Mathamatica* can "reason" about `Piecewise` expressions, but cannot do so with collections of rewriting rules, so `f` is not a suitable function to feed to symbolic methods.

Comment: Thanks for the response. Quick clarifying question on one sentence in your answer: you say `f[1]` is just a pattern, any expression that matches that pattern will be rewritten as `5`". Isn't `f[1]` the only expression that matches that pattern?

Comment: @user106860 Yes. Of course, it could be a subexpression of some more complicated expression.